# Will a wild shaped druid lose or retain abilities given to him by allies?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wild-shape

If I cast *haste* and give bardic inspiration to my Druid ally, will he be able to use these abilities if he then transforms using his wildshape?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect he won't be able to use those spells/features?

Comment: Bardic inspiration doesn't give a druid any special ability. Lorewise, it inspires the character. Mechanically, it lets the player add to its dice roll.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The druid retains any abilities that their animal form can use.

Wild Shape states:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, **or other source** and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so. *(PHB, 67)*

Emphasis mine.

There's nothing that would prevent the druid from using Haste or Bardic Inspiration that has been given to them by someone else while in animal form, so they are able to maintain those effects and make use of them.

Comment: This is why a wildshaped druid can use rage if he/she is multiclassed barbarian, but a polymorphed barbarian can not. Wild Shape allows you to retain your features, polymorph replaces them.